# Angular Model Function is not Visible to Component

Tags: angular

I have a User model that I want to use and display a "full name" based on the properties.

```
export class User {

  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;

  constructor() {
  }

  //getting called later
  getFullName() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }

}
```

I call try to use the `getFullName()` function in the HTML component:

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let user of userList" [ngValue]="user">
    {{user.getFullName()}}
  </option>
</select>
```

If I call `user.firstName` and `user.lastName`, the full name displays as expected, but with the above code I instead get the below error:

```
MyComponent.html:3 ERROR TypeError: _v.context.$implicit.getFullName is not a function
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (MyComponent.html:3)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:45294)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44277)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:44594)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44272)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:44565)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44278)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
```

Here is my retrieval of the User list:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    userList: User[];

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.httpClient.get<User[]>("http://localhost:8090/user/getAll").subscribe(
            userList => {
                this.userList = userList;
                console.log(userList);
            }
        );
    }

}
```

Why does it not recognize `getFullName()` as a function?

Comment: How are you setting userList and where is it comming from? I'd guess you parsed it from json but haven't created an instance of user. Am I right?

Comment: Can you share how you are creating the userList.

Comment: @Raj singh and lenlisondc Updated the question to include the retrieval. I probably should have added that initially... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You will need to somehow instantiate the object. getting the ajax request and assigning to a variable is not enough. That doesn't instantiate the Typescript class. if you instantiate the object then you can use its methods.

In your case, a easy way to go about it is to make a copy of the object `Object.assign(new User, user)`. I just dont think its worth making a copy of the object just to display the persons first and last name.

Comment: if I remove "user.", it makes an red-line error since the compiler can't see where getFullName() is defined

Comment: is this html the template for that class?

Comment: @CubeSmithy , I updated my answer with your updated question

Comment: I see your point. It just seems to me that Angular should be smart enough to somehow map the returned json to an object. While this case is simpler (and you're right that it's honestly not worth the effort here), I could see other cases that would be very convenient to map json to objects. Writing Object.assign in a loop just feels off...